# Rotate a div with text. Problems with Safari

Tags: css, rotation

I try to rotate a div with text inside. I can rotate it but I am confused:
- Why it does not position left:0  ?
- Why it looses definition only when it rotates? This only happens with Safari. (It works well with Chrome and Firefox)

In the example you can see a horizontal div with a normal behavior and the horizontal with the 2 problems:
http://jsfiddle.net/YLpPj/

HTML:

```
<div id="vertical">vertical button</div>
<div id="horizontal">horizontal button</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#666;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

#horizontal {
    position:fixed;
    top:200px; left:0px;
    width:150px; height:35px; line-height:35px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
}

#vertical {
    position:fixed;
    top:20px; left:0px;
    width:150px; height:35px; line-height:35px;
    background:#f2f2f2;

    /* different, to rotate: */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);/* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* ie9 */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2); /* ie8 */
    writing-mode:tb-rl; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: Browser sets element position according to your `left` and `top` and then rotates it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This makes sense. What about the definition of the text?

Comment: The text when it is turner vertical, looses definition. I think it only happens with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
HTML Code:

<div class="vertical">
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>K</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
CSS Code:

.vertical {
height:auto;
width:25px;
background-color:violet;
color:white;
border-radius:5px;
}
.tab
 {
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

[Live Demo of Vertical Text in Div](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/L32kL/)